# How to install a python package from tar.gz without using setup.py

Tags: python, linux, package, debian, mysql-python

i am trying to install MySQL Connector/Python version 8.0.24 packaged in a tar.gz on Debian.

I have tried extracting the files but since there is no setup.py i don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Since the official distribution contains a `setup.py` I wonder what kind of archive you have there. In any case you could try `pip install mysql-connector-python`.

Comment: i must install the package using the tar.gz archive

Comment: Where did you get the tar.gz ?

Comment: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-python/

Comment: With your link, we see only `*.deb" files, not "*.tar.gz" files.

Comment: they're under the platform independent tab